# Внутри функции возврат значения лучше через переменную или сразу через выражение? PEP8

Tags: python, pep8

Возник спор по стилю кодирования, по поводу простейшей вещи. Правых нет, но оно и понятно. Хотелось бы узнать, у тех, кто хоршо знает правила. Что PEP8 говорит по этому поводу? Как будет лучше?

```
# Первый вариант через переменную. Такую переменную можно логировать, в пичарме.
def my_func(x):
    n = x + 2
    return n

# Второй вариант, без лишних переменных. Меньше строк.
def my_func_two(x):
    return x + 2
```

Comment: Мне нравятся такие споры, ибо многие пренебрегают основами. А зря:-) Выражается это потом в конкретных деньгах (идущих из трудозатрат). Спасибо за вопрос! :-) См. мой анализ ниже..

Comment: ¿А результат вызова функции нельзя показать?

Comment: "Такую переменную можно логировать, в пичарме." - логирование (аргументов и возвращаемого значения) может быть поверх функции быть прикручено через декоратор, см. https://github.com/sighalt/logdecorator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PEP8 ничего об этом не говорит**, единственное, что можно процитировать: "Код читается намного больше раз, чем пишется".

**Ближе к этому случаю PEP20 (он же Дзен Python).**
Он тоже не дает конкретных рекомендаций, но гласит, в частности (я выбрал подходящее к этому случаю):
"3. Простое лучше сложного."
"8. Особые случаи не настолько особые, чтобы нарушать правила."
"9. При этом практичность важнее безупречности."
"13. Должен существовать один - и, желательно, только один – очевидный способ сделать что-то."

Тогда, исходя из 3, 8 и (отчасти) 13 надо выбрать код 2. Но, исходя из 9 необходимо посмотреть на конкретную задачу и определить, что *практически* требуется от задачи.

**Итого:**
*Если логирование нужно постоянно, то оставим код 1.

Если оно нужно только на момент отладки, то оставим только на момент отладки и уберем в финальной версии, перейдя к коду 2.*